# У меня сомнения по поводу частицы "на". Допустима ли она в этом предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"...уделять внимание на транспортные расходы, расходы на аренду, энергосбережение".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлог *на* (в примере допущен повтор!) уместен в сочетании с глаголом *обращать* (на что, на кого?): «Обращать внимание на транспортные расходы».

Ваше предложение могло бы выглядеть и так: «Уделять внимание расходам на транспорт, аренду, энергосбережение!»

Answer (score 1):

**...уделять внимание транспортным расходам, расходам на аренду, энергосбережению.**
Или
**...уделять внимание транспортным расходам, расходам на аренду, энергосбережение.**

(Потому что из вопроса непонятно, *"уделять внимание... энергосбережению"* или *"уделять внимание... расходам на... энергосбережение"*.)

Правильно: уделять внимание *кому/чему* ([источник: Грамота.Ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=307888))